# Json deserialize unknown or generic model type

Tags: c#, json, json.net

This may not be possible.

Here is working code:

```
HttpResponseMessage playerResponse = await client.GetAsync("2018/export?TYPE=players&DETAILS=1&SINCE=&PLAYERS=9988%2C13604&JSON=1");
if (playerResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var json = await playerResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var o = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MFLPlayerAPIResult>(json);
    playerList = o.PlayerData.MflPlayers.ToList();                    
}
```

The problem is I have  lots of different models similar to `MFLPlayerAPIResult` like my code in the above, they all use different request strings.  I am trying to build a function like this:

```
private async Task<Object> CreateListFromJson(Type jsonclass, string request, HttpClient client)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(request);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var o = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<jsonclass>(json);
        return (o);
    }
    return (null);
}
```

where the `Object` returned would be the same model as the `Type jsonclass` used in the parameters, then I could use the function like this:

```
playerList = CreateListFromJson(MFLPlayerAPIResult, request, client).PlayerData.MflPlayers.ToList();
```

And use it multiple times over and over with different request strings and model types.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know the type ahead of time you can just take in a generic parameter like so:

```
private async Task<T> CreateListFromJson<T>(string request, HttpClient client)
    where T: class
{
    var myObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(item);
    //...
}
```

If you don't know the type until compile time you can call the deserialize at runtime by passing the type

```
private async Task<Object> CreateListFromJson(Type jsonclass, string request, HttpClient client)
{
    var myObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(item, jsonclass);
    //...
}
```

Comment: Ugh... and return `Object` when you could go generics all the way? `async Task<T> CreateListFromJson<T>(string request, HttpClient client)`

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I'm under the impression that he doesn't know the type at compile time, because he's passing it in, but I'll make some edits

Comment: Thank you, I was just missing the information on how to use T properly, Did not realize I needed it in the second set of <> after CreateListFromJson.  Any suggestions on how to hand an "else" error if status code is not success? My function wont let me return null

Comment: Got it. default(T)